# Comparing JSON data broken on iOS7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsnumber, ios7.1

I have an existing app on the App Store that's suddenly developed a few issues related to the iOS7.1 update. This is one I can't get my head around though, it looks as though it should (and it used to) work. I'm trying to check whether the "Success" key of a JSON string is equal to '1'.

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *op = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:req success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] decrementActivityCount];
    if ([[JSON objectForKey:@"Success"] isEqualToValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]) {
        // succeeded
        NSLog(@"Reached success while submitting");

    } else {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [JSON objectForKey:@"Success"]);
        // Success was not 0
    }
}failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    // parse/download error
}];
```

The program always reaches the `else` statement even if the Success key is 1. Here's the debug print of the JSON object:

```
Printing description of JSON:
{
    EntryId = 5235;
    EntryLink = "https://cpdme.wufoo.com/api/v3/forms/z7x4a9/entries.json?Filter1=EntryId+Is_equal_to+5235";
    Success = 1;
}
```

Comment: Please print the actual data that was parsed. It could be that the server is sending strings for EntryId and Success; unfortunately you can't see this when you print the parsed dictionary. Or check whether [[JSON objectForKey:@"Success" isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] or [NSString class].

Comment: Surely the printed description shows this? If they were strings, they would be wrapped in double quotes like the `EntryLink` is?

Comment: See the comment on @Wain's answer - both classes are the same type (`NSNumber`)

Comment: Strings that don't require quotes won't have quotes around them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider changing your code to:

```
NSNumber *statusValue = [JSON objectForKey:@"Success"];

if ([statusValue boolValue]) {
    ...
```

as this has a much broader scope for correctly identifying truth. It will also quietly deal with the value being a string instance.

I guess your current code suffers from a class type mismatch during the comparison. Log the class and contents of `[JSON objectForKey:@"Success"]` and `[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]` to verify the results.

Comment: Hi Wain, the output of the classes is: JSON Success Key Class: `__NSCFNumber`
Number class: `__NSCFNumber`

Comment: Looks reasonable. Does editing the code give the correct result?

Comment: Just tried it - it does, thanks! Crazy that it only changed in iOS7.1

Comment: There is no need to typecast `(NSNumber *)[JSON objectForKey:@"Success"]`

Comment: @hypercrypt, true, didn't really think about it, just err'd on the side of caution when typing code direct into a browser...

Comment: There's a good reason for the cast: Without it, the compiler will let you call methods that are not NSNumber methods without complaining. Even better is to assign to a local NSNumber* variable; gives you a chance to examine it in the debugger, and the compiler will tell when you shouldn't have used a conversion.

Comment: @gnasher729, the compiler will still let you call methods that might not exist even if you do cast. A cast is like saying 'I promise' to the compiler, but it isn't necessarily true at runtime. My answer does assign to a local variable, but again, at runtime this could prove to be a lie...